# image.position is not a function

Tags: jquery, position

When I set something like :

```
var image = $('img');
var pos = image.position();

console.log(pos.left);
```

I keep getting the error  "image.position is not a function" . Please would someone tell me why is it happening?

[edit] 
Thanks everyone..... I finally found out - was as simple typo 
 >:O 
I really need to get a better keyboard.

Comment: Care to tell us what the typo was?

Comment: Not exactly a typo. Its more of a mistake. Instead of doing - var image = $('img'); -- I had done -- var image = $('img').src(); -- Naturally it should be unable to find that text's position.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're using (and have included) jQuery?

The only thing I can think of is that you're using another JS library that uses the `$` shortcut but one that does not have a `position()` method.

Try replacing `$` with `jQuery`.

While you're at it, what version of jQuery are you using? `position()` was added in 1.2.

```
alert(jQuery().jquery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any img on the page? If it is not there $('img').length will be 0. You get this error only when the length is 0.

Comment: Nope, returns `null` for me given an empty jQuery object, not "position is not a function"

Comment: yes. $('img').length return 7, the length of the file - 006.jpg. I have added an image and I am having the same error..

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, you should do this:

```
var left = $(elem).css("left");
var top = $(elem).css("top");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think May be some problem with `$('img')`. use # front if its ID.

Try Like:

```
var pos = $("#myimage").position(); // returns an object with the attribute top and left
pos.top;  // top offset position
pos.left; // left offset position
```

Comment: No, `$('img').position()` will work fine (and give you a [`null`](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/sXz3V/)) even if there aren't any `<img>` elements, it won't give you "position is not a function".

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select on id, class or all the img on the page?

If you are doing it by id should be var image=$('#img') ; if doing it by class  should be var $('.img'); if you are selecting all img then I don't think you can do position() since you will get an array of img instead of just one unless you do

```
$('img')[0].position();//assuming you only care about the first one
```

Comment: I think it will use the first element in the collection. For example, on this page (6 images), `jQuery("img").position().left == 613`

Comment: I have a simple html with just 1 image. I used 'img' for it - without id or class names.

Comment: No, `$('img')[0].position()` isn't right. `$(x)[0]` is either `null` or a DOM object and DOM objects don't have `position()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    var image = $('img');
    var pos = image.position();

    alert(pos.left);

});
```

This works for me, did you wrap it in a ready function?

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MMaR9/

Comment: I thought that too but an empty jQuery object will return `null` for `position()`, not "position is not a function"

Comment: @Phil - Not sure I follow, what exactly isn't working and why? :/

Comment: The error is "image.position is not a function". If the OP is actually using jQuery, this is impossible to get, even if the DOM isn't loaded or there are no images in the markup. For example, this page has no `<abbr>` elements, but `jQuery("abbr").position()` returns `null` without throwing an error.